# C#: IIS server fails to run a pg_dump Proccess through CMD.exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, iis, pg-dump

I'm trying to create a function that backs up one of my important tables using pg_dump --table. The function runs successfully on my localhost and does the dump. but when it is run by my program through IIS on the server, it doesnt seem to do anything.

my project uses .NET Framework 4.7.2 , Here is my program's code:

```
try{
    var process = new Process();
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Website\\Logs\\";
    string fileName = startInfo.WorkingDirectory+RandomString();
    startInfo.Arguments =
     $"/c set PGPASSWORD={userPassword}&pg_dump --file {fileName} --host {Ip} --port 5432 --username {userName} --no-password --verbose --format=d --table public.clients {DB_Name}";
    ServerLogs.SaveLog(startInfo.Arguments); //i am saving the logs
    startInfo.Verb = "runas"; //run as administrator
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Close();
    return "Success";
  }catch (Exception x)
   { 
    return x.Message; 
   }
```

As u can see, i am logging the arguments field on the server. here is the CMD that was generated and executed :

`/c set PGPASSWORD=MyPassword&pg_dump --file C:\Website\Logs\abcd\FileName123123 --host mycluster.eu-north-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port 5432 --username test--no-password --verbose --format=d --table public.clients CRM`

this CMD that was created is good, when i copy it to the EC2 server's terminal it runs and dumps the table successfully into my specified path. But when it is run by my program through IIS, it only saves the log, but the proccess itself is not dumping the table. not creating any file. pg_dump is recognized and configured well in my env variables.

1.I was thinking the code is ok because it runs well locally

2.I was thinking the CMD is ok because it runs well on the server's terminal.

3.I tried changing the startInfo.arguments to be "type nul > somefile.txt" to see if IIS has permissions to create files on this folder, and it ran successfully.. so i was thinking this isnt a permission issue.

But I could be wrong. Because it is not working.
I tried several methods and solutions online and I am kinda clueless. I would very much appriciate any help or suggestions. Thank you very much!

Comment: IIS runs under a non-admin service account so `startInfo.Verb = "runas"; //run as administrator` is not going to work because of UAC.

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks for the reply, I tried at first without it too, though it didnt work. thats why I added this I thought it might help but it didnt.. facing the issue both with it and without

Comment: Spinning out processes from a web app on IIS requires you to understand all the differences there, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 so "it runs well locally" or "it runs well on the server's terminal" in fact guarantees nothing. Many of the command line utilities out there were never designed to run in a web app context. You should consider using ADO.NET to connect to the database and perform equivalent operations.